# How to configure Spring 3 with SLF4J over LOG4J2 using Log4jConfigurer?

Tags: spring, logging, slf4j, log4j2, spring-3

I am trying to configure my application to use SLF4J with log4j2 for logging. 
The application uses Spring 3. The console logger is working but none of the Rolling appenders seems to be logging anything.

Here is how application logging is configured :

- pom.xml

  ```
  <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
      <version>3.2.18.RELEASE</version>
      <type>jar</type>
      <scope>compile</scope>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
      <version>3.2.18.RELEASE</version>
      <type>jar</type>
      <scope>compile</scope>
      <exclusions>
          <exclusion>
              <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
              <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
          </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
      <version>2.11.0</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
      <version>2.11.0</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>log4j-slf4j-impl</artifactId>
      <version>2.11.0</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
  ```
- web.xml

  ```
  <listener>
         <listener-class>
             org.springframework.web.util.Log4jConfigListener
         </listener-class>
  </listener>
  ```
- Application.xml

log4j properties :

```
    log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, CONSOLE

log4j.appender.CONSOLE=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.CONSOLE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.CONSOLE.layout.ConversionPattern=[%d{ISO8601} EST] %X{sessionId} %X{requestTokenId} %X{clientIP} %p %m%n

log4j.appender.TEST_APPENDER=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.TEST_APPENDER.File=a.log
log4j.appender.TEST_APPENDER.MaxFileSize=10MB
log4j.appender.TEST_APPENDER.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.TEST_APPENDER.layout.ConversionPattern=[%d{ISO8601} EST] %X{sessionId} %X{requestTokenId} %X{clientIP} %p %m%n
log4j.appender.TEST_APPENDER.MaxBackupIndex=8
log4j.appender.TEST_APPENDER.Threshold=DEBUG

log4j.logger.com.abhishek=DEBUG, CONSOLE, TEST_APPENDER
```

application xml :

```
<bean id="log4jInitialization" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingFactoryBean">
        <property name="targetClass" value="org.springframework.util.Log4jConfigurer" />
        <property name="targetMethod" value="initLogging" />
        <property name="arguments">
            <list>
                <value>${config.dir}/log4j.properties</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

logging code :

```
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Test.class);
LOGGER.debug("Testing...");
```

Comment: You don't. The `Log4jConfigListener` is for Log4J NOT Log4j2.

Comment: @M.Deinum - Is there a way we can configure Spring3 to use SLF4J with LOG4J2 ?

Comment: Just configure log4j2 as you would normally do. The `Log4jConfigListener` isn't mandatory (only if you want very early log initialization).

Comment: @M.Deinum...are there any examples on the internet that you might know of. I couldn't find many examples for Spring3, SLF4J and log4j2.

Comment: Just follow the regular log4j2 configuration. The fact that you use SLF4j doesn't matter.